# Detecting when text in a textbox changes (while typing)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, textchanged

The `.TextChanged` event on a `TextBox` fires only after the `TextBox` loses focus. Is there a way to detect every character that is being typed while the user is typing it?

I know the radio button has a similar event called `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` to detect when the button is clicked without having to wait for it to lose focus. I was trying to find something similar for a `TextBox`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only allow specific characters in textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607087/only-allow-specific-characters-in-textbox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true that the `TextChanged` event is triggered only when the textbox loses the focus. This code

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TextBox1.Text = " & TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Yields the following output (in the Output window) when typing "Hello":

> TextBox1.Text = H
>   TextBox1.Text = He
>   TextBox1.Text = Hel
>   TextBox1.Text = Hell
>   TextBox1.Text = Hello

However, it will also fire when you delete characters, so if your intention is to filter characters use one of the key events.

Comment: You are correct. However, it wasn't working for me when I was testing it. I still don't know why, but it is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) or [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) events. These will fire whenever you press a key.