# How to disable Spacebar in a TextBox C#

Tags: c#

i am trying to use `SendKeys.Send()` to send `textbox1.Text` to a application ( like notepad ), and i want to disable or remove spaces from the textbox so there is no spaces in the application.
Any help is appreciated!

```
 private void InfoSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        SendKeys.Send(input_info);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        input_info = textBox1.Text;

    }
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607087/only-allow-specific-characters-in-textbox

Comment: why don't you try to override the `keypress` event of `textbox` and send `nil` while `char` value is `32` for space...

Comment: post the code you are using to sendkeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user can input white spaces to TextBox then you can write this:

```
private void InfoSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    input_info = input_info.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    SendKeys.Send(input_info);
}
```