# Enter only numbers 1 or 2

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

How can you make it so that only the numbers 1 or 2 can be entered into the textbox? And you can also use the Backspace key. The maximum length of textbox characters is one.
I know how to enter only numbers:

```
char number = e.KeyChar;
if (!Char.IsDigit(number) && number != 8)
{
e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char number = e.KeyChar;
if (number != '1' && number != '2' && number != '\b')
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

or just

```
e.Handled = e.KeyChar != '1' && e.KeyChar != '2' && e.KeyChar != '\b';
```

or for more expressiveness

```
private static readonly char[] allowedChars = { '1', '2', '\b' };
// ...
e.Handled = !allowedChars.Contains(e.KeyChar);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is use RegularExpressions and you can check any input with expressions.

I think you should visit this question:
[Only allow specific characters in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607087/only-allow-specific-characters-in-textbox)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the NumericUpDown control instead of a TextBox. There you can set min to 1, max to 2, and your user can enter numbers or use the arrow keys to increase/decrease.

If you MUST use a TextBox, then set it MaxLength property to 1, and add a KeyDown event and handler. In the handler you can do:

```
if(!(e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.D2 || E.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)) 
{
    // Of course, you can add even more keys up there. For example, you might add Keys.Numpad1 etc...
    e.handled = true;
}
```

So, for the TextBox you already did the right thing, basically.

Answer (score 1):

> Use [SuppressKeyPress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress?view=netframework-4.8) property

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        /*
         * 8:   backspace
         * 49:  1
         * 50:  2
         */

        int[] validKeys = {8, 49, 50};
        if (!validKeys.Contains(e.KeyValue))
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume all you need is something like the following in the textbox's TextChanged event?

```
if (textbox.text != "1" && textbox.text != "2")
{
    textbox.text = string.empty;
}
```

I'm not sure what the `number != 8` is for in your question?

Comment: This is a bad practice

Comment: @Roberto - so is calling something out for being bad practice without saying _why_ it is bad practice.
It all seems a little moot though when any answer which actually answers the question will be bad practice - a TextBox is inappropriate for a boolean input from the user. A Checkbox or Radiobuttons sure - _maybe_ a NumericUpDown but even that isn't really appropriate.